# Why do I get conflicts while creating new Django app

Tags: django, django-apps, manage.py

`tn_gram_backend` is the main Django project folder.

I created a new folder `staging` and inside that I am trying to create another Django app called `ddc` but it is throwing me the following error as show in the below image. Please suggest how to fix this.

```
'ddc' conflicts with the name of an existing python module and cannot be used as an app name
```

Comment: It's not about Django itself, it's about python package management

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's because in your `tn_gram_backend` folder you already have an app called `ddc`. And since you're trying to create a new app with the same name you get the collision. (Even when it's a subfolder). If you name it `ddc_stagning` it should work. Having the same name on modules can cause issues with imports.

Answer (score 0):

You'll end up with two apps called 'ddc' which as the error suggests is a conflict. You may be able to rename the app in the apps.py file in staging/ddc/app.py but I suspect your staging folder really belongs outside of the tn_gram_backend folder.